# How can I merge two data frames with 500+ columns each, and 200+ overlapping columns?

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I have several data frames that I need to merge into the one data frame to rule them all. The master data frame will end up with thousands of columns. All of the data frames have an ID column to join on. One problem is that hundreds of columns are duplicated across data frames. Another problem is that a handful of those columns contain inconsistent values. I would like to find a way to

1. Combine all data frames, keeping only 1 "master column" of data if there are duplicate column names and the values do not conflict between data frames
2. Keep both both columns of data if they share the same name, but they have conflicting values.

Are there any packages that can help automate this? Or am I going to be stuck writing a lot of code/manually checking data?

Comment: do they all have the same number of rows and same IDs?

Comment: @flodel Different number of rows in each data frame. The IDs are accurate across data frames, though not all IDs will be found in each data frame. We do have one data frame that contains all of the IDs--so we'd probably join all data frames to that one. We are going to have a fair amount of NA values in the ID isn't found in one or more of the data frames, but that is ok for the analysis.

Comment: Can you reshape your data to a "longer" format? I.e., reduce the number of columns by creating factor columns? Thousands of columns normally isn't a preferred way to store data. This might be relevant here: http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf. Your second requirement will probably make this operation less efficient. You might have to modify `merge.data.frame`.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the package [*safejoin*](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/safejoin) which solves this very succintly :

```
#devtools::install_github("moodymudskipper/safejoin")
library(safejoin)
```

See the following data frames, A is identical in both, B is different in `df1` and `df2`,
`C` and `D` are in only one data frame

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:2, A = 3:4, B= 5:6,  C = 7:8)
df2 <- data.frame(id = 1:2, A = 3:4, B= 9:10, D = 11:12)

library(tidyverse)
safe_full_join(df1, df2, by = "id", conflict = ~ if(identical(.x, .y)) .x else 
                   map2( .x, .y,~tibble(df1=.x,df2=.y))) %>%
  unnest(.sep="_")
#   id A C  D B_df1 B_df2
# 1  1 3 7 11     5     9
# 2  2 4 8 12     6    10L
```